# how to serialize a pojo with jackson in 2 different ways?

Tags: java, json, rest, serialization, jackson

I have a different rest endpoints that returns different parts of the same object. how can i serialize the same object in 2 different ways? do I need different DTO or is there a simpler way?

Comment: Create two different `interface`. Pass those into the serialization.

Answer (score 1):

You can create different views for different rest endpoints.

See the documentation here: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJsonViews